# What are the corrections that should be done?

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am trying to create a stack in data structures using C. Three files are .h main.c and methods.c  .
There is an issue with expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'Stack' (Stack *stack) in both the .h file and methods.c file.
I found another error that is array subscript is not an integer return stack->data[++stack->top] = value; in the metods.c file

I can't find the reasons for the errors. Can you fix them?

.h

```
#ifndef stackArray
#define stackArray

#define MAX_SIZE 10

struct StackNode{

    int data[MAX_SIZE];
    struct StackNode *top;

} Stack;

void initialize(Stack *stack);
int isFull(Stack *stack);
int isEmpty(Stack *stack);
void push(Stack *stack, int value);
int pop(Stack *stack);
int peek(Stack *stack);


#endif
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stackArray.h"

int main() {
    Stack stack;
    initialize(&stack);

    push(&stack, 10);
    push(&stack, 20);
    push(&stack, 30);

    if (!isEmpty(&stack)) {
        printf("Top element: %d\n", peek(&stack));
    } else {
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
    }

    printf("Popped: %d\n", pop(&stack));
    printf("Popped: %d\n", pop(&stack));

    if (!isEmpty(&stack)) {
        printf("Top element: %d\n", peek(&stack));
    } else {
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

methods.c

```
#include "stackArray.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void initialize(Stack *stack) {
    stack->top = -1;
}

int isFull(Stack *stack) {
    return stack->top == MAX_SIZE - 1;
}

int isEmpty(Stack *stack) {
    return stack->top == -1;
}

void push(Stack *stack, int value) {
    if (isFull(stack)) {
        printf("Stack Overflow: Cannot push element %d\n", value);
        return;
    }

    stack->data[++stack->top] = value;
    printf("Pushed %d onto the stack\n", value);
}

int pop(Stack *stack) {
    if (isEmpty(stack)) {
        printf("Stack Underflow: Cannot pop from an empty stack\n");
        return -1; // Return a sentinel value to indicate underflow
    }

    return stack->data[stack->top--];
}

int peek(Stack *stack) {
    if (isEmpty(stack)) {
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
        return -1; // Return a sentinel value to indicate underflow
    }

    return stack->data[stack->top];
}
```

Comment: Through the logic of your code, `top` is an index, so define it as integral type...

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
struct StackNode{

    int data[MAX_SIZE];
    struct StackNode *top;

} Stack;
```

Defines a struct called `struct StackNode` and creates an *instance* of that struct named `Stack`.  It does *not* create a type.

For that, you need to use `typedef`:

```
typedef struct StackNode{

    int data[MAX_SIZE];
    struct StackNode *top;

} Stack;
```

---

As for the second problem, you are using `top` as an index, but you declared it as a pointer.

```c
struct StackNode *top;
```

should be

```c
ssize_t top;
```

Comment: `top` is a pointer. This conflicts with usage: `stack->data[stack->top--]`